# In golang how calling a function with and without trailing brackets works when using net/http

Tags: function, http, go, parameters

In the main function, I have a gorilla mux router, and a function to handle the route.

```
var router = mux.NewRouter()
func main() {   
    router.HandleFunc("/", ParseSlash)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

and ParseSlash looks like

```
const slash = `<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <label for="name">User name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>`

func ParseSlash(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)  {
    fmt.Fprintf(response, slash)
}
```

However, in main, we are not calling the function as `ParseSlash()`, but `ParseSlash` inside `router.HandleFunc()`. Where do the function get the parameters from, if we are not providing explicitely? What is this way of calling a function termed as?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not "calling" the function from main, you are providing it as a argument to `HandleFunc`, registering it to be called for the path "/" in the `mux.Router`. This pattern of providing a function to be called later is typically known as a "callback".

Your `ParseSlash` function is of the type [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc)

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

Your function is eventually called by the `http.Server` via its `ServeHTTP` method (here, via the `mux.Router`), passing the arguments shown. When the function is called, the `http.ResponseWriter` and `*http.Request` arguments are for the individual http request being handled.

Comment: In addition, the "function without brackets" as you named it, is called a callback and is a common technique, for which you can find lots of resources online. It is very common (and imho essential) in e.g. JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple callback. You need that, when you want to call some function in the future, but now you don't have enough information to do it. Look - http.ListenAndServe create a server and waits for client.

You cannot call function ParseSlash, because it make sense after client will connect and will send address "/". When it happened router would have enough information to call your code back with arguments http.ResponseWriter and *http.Request.

Now you should learn how closures works - https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25 . And you will done let's return back to http server https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/middlewares-golang-best-practices-examples/ .